# Why is toggling images visibility with JavaScript slow / needs repaint?

Tags: javascript, image, performance, visibility, show-hide

I have a few images on my website stacked up on each other (absolute positioning within relative DIV). I like to toggle those images upon mousemove event. I tried it by add/remove a CSS class. This works so far. However, in Chromes Timeline I see quite long repaints including "image decode" and "image resize" on each event. I tried it with different "hiding techniques" like "display:none", "visibility:hidden" and "z-Index:0". Toggling display or visibility didn't make a difference, but the zIndex version took VERY long because every single images gets redrawn. So I'm stucking here. How can I toggle visibility without having redraws at all? At least the Image decoding should not be necesarry?! Here's a code snippet how I'm doing it in JS:

```
var currentImgElem = document.getElementById(elem_id_curr);
var showImgElem = document.getElementById(elem_id_show);

currentImgElem.classList.add("hide");
showImgElem.classList.remove("hide");
```

whereas "hide" is one of:

```
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
z-Index:0;
```

One more confusion: When I'm doing this with images drawn to a canvas, everything is fine!

Comment: I have a feeling you might have another global style problem, CSS3 shadows and the like cause all kinds of expensive and seemingly unnecessary repaint behaviors in current browsers, but in any event if these things aren't working even though they should, one thing you haven't tried is setting a high negative margin-left on a position:relative element—theoretically this should not cause reflow or repaint, although browsers can technically do these at any time they choose. If you set up a fiddle we can all try things and see what works together.

Comment: thanks for the margin-tip will try it soon. here's some fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFKs5/7/ However, i'm not using any fancy JS or CSS. all very basic.

Comment: hey Plynx, i tried the margin trick but it shows the same problem. i have around 220ms Paint with 120ms for image decode and 100ms for resize. so it's the same as toggling display or visibility.

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to work; I guess there aren't image resources and the javascript isn't being called. What I was going to try was setting the style directly rather than modifying the class. This should be a less intrusive way of setting some elements like visibility. Something like `currentImgElem.style.visibility = "hidden";
    showImgElem.style.visibility = "";` Maybe that will help it to know you aren't changing potentially any style attribute, but only visibility.